Problems connecting camera to raspberry pi 5
Recently I have bought a Raspberry Pi 5. I am trying to run a camera module with it, but I am having some trouble.
The camera module I got is this: https://www.kubii.com/en/cameras-sensors/2270-raspberry-pi-fisheye-5mp-night-vision-camera-with-2-ir-3272496011823.html
It is an unofficial camera module, and despite the datasheet being missing in the previous webpage I believe it has the OV5647 sensor chip, as it is a 5MP camera. Here I provide a picture of the sensor:

I provide a picture of the connection for the camera too:

and the connection in the DISP/CAM1 port of my pi-5:

I followed this instructions to try to get it running: https://docs.arducam.com/Raspberry-Pi-Camera/Native-camera/5MP-OV5647/. With that, my /boot/firmware/config.txt file looks like this:
# For more options and information see
# http://rptl.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented
# /boot/firmware/overlays/README

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=0

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load initramfs files, if found
auto_initramfs=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# Don't have the firmware create an initial video= setting in cmdline.txt.
# Use the kernel's default instead.
disable_fw_kms_setup=1

# Run in 64-bit mode
arm_64bit=1

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[cm5]
dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=host

[all]
dtoverlay=ov5647

After following the instructions, I reboot the pi-5, I run libcamera-hello --list-cameras but I get a "No cameras available!" message.
I have read in this thread (https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2152742&sid=b0e52999edcdcadbac9679da8c445b63#p2151001) that the Bookworm kernel wasn't playing along nicely with the OV5647 sensor. However, the thread is already some months old so I suppose I should have an up-to-date kernel already.
I also don't think it's a connection issue as the IR leds in the camera module light up when the pi-5 is powered up. I don't think its a pi-5 port issue either as I have changed the camera from DISP/CAM1 to DISP/CAM0, updated /boot/firmware/config.txt to show dtoverlay=ov5647,cam0, and still have the same results. Also, I have a touchscreen (the other ribbon you can see in the third picture) that works no problem both in DISP/CAM1 and DISP/CAM0. Out of desperation, I tried setting the dtoverlay option to several other sensor chips (the ones you can find in a table here https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/OV5647-70_5MP_OIS_Camera), in case I didn't actually have a OV5647, but still couldn't get my raspberry to detect the camera module.
I am pretty much a newcomer to DIY projects and specifically to raspberry pi, so I am sure I am missing out something. I am out of ideas to try, so I would be happy if you could help me with this.
